# Taxes in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, savings, pension

I am an EU citizen that recently moved to the UK. I lived in another EU country for the last few years and started a pension saving account there. This account is still open but I live and work in the UK now, and it's not clear to me whether I need to declare the money I'm saving. Is this considered an income? I don't (currently) receive any capital gains or interest, the only advantage compared to a standard bank account is that part of the interest is contributed by the government of the other EU country.

Do you have experience with this kind of situation? Could you eventually recommend a website with information regarding taxes for foreigners in the UK? I am aware that one option is calling the HMS customs office, which I might have to do anyway.

The amount I've saved so far is low (less than 5000 euros) if that makes any difference. My bank is also aware of the fact that I've moved to the UK.

Answer (score 1):

The only time when you need to pay taxes on an existing pension is when the pension pays out after you retire, or if you get a lump sum out of the pension, around the time when you retire. The growth in value of your pension fund is not income.

Comment: That entirely depends on the relevant tax rules, which may be some combination of the UK and the other EU countries ones.